# Google Cloud Run | Angular project deployment as serverless container | COPY failed: no source files were specified

Tags: docker, nginx

1. Environment : Google cloud run
2. Project : Angular 8
3. Deployment type : Serverless container
4. Creating a linux container from windows 10 pro PC
5. Here is my cloudbuild.yaml file below :

```
steps:

  # build the container image
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args: [ build, -t, gcr.io/<project name here>/<container name here>, . ]

  # push the container image to Container Registry
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args: [ push, gcr.io/<project name here>/<container name here> ]

  # Deploy container image to Cloud Run
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    args: [ beta, run, deploy, <container name here>, --image, gcr.io/<project name here>/<container name here>, --platform, managed, --region, us-central1 ]


images:

- gcr.io/<project name here>/<container name here>
```

6. Here is my Dockerfile below :

```
FROM node:10.9-alpine AS build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install && npm run build --prod

FROM nginx:latest
COPY /etc/nginx/*.conf /etc/nginx/

## Create the new /var/logs/nginx folder
RUN mkdir /var/logs
RUN mkdir /var/logs/nginx
## Copy a new configuration file setting listen port to 8080
COPY /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
## Expose port 8080
EXPOSE 8080
## Remove default nginx website
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
## From 'build' stage copy over the artifacts in dist folder to default nginx public folder
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

7. Here is my .dockerignore file

```
# Node
node_modules/

# Angular
dist/
```

8. Here is my error below from nginx

```
Step #0: Step 6/13 : COPY /etc/nginx/*.conf /etc/nginx/
Step #0: COPY failed: no source files were specified
Finished Step #0
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: exit status 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) build 731c37fb-f282-4649-972e-aec572b33bca completed with status "FAILURE"
```

What am I missing here?  Any clue is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is this file `/etc/nginx/*.conf` come from your environment? or form the previous layer?

Answer (score 0):

According to this:

```
Step #0: Step 6/13 : COPY /etc/nginx/*.conf /etc/nginx/
Step #0: COPY failed: no source files were specified
```

The problem is you `COPY` command. When you use `COPY /etc/nginx/*.conf /etc/nginx/` you should make sure that the files you want to copy are inside the build contexts. So what you should do is to ensure that the *.conf files are in the right directory. It should look like this:

```
/etc/nginx/*.conf
/etc/Dockerfile
```

Or like this:

```
/etc/nginx/folderName/*.conf
/etc/nginx/Dockerfile
```

Another way is to use `VOLUME` instead of `COPY`. What `VOLUME` does is to mount the directory you want to a directory inside the container. It doesn't copy the files per se, it creates a "reference" to the actual directory instead.

**Mount volume (-v, --read-only)**

```
$ docker  run  -v `pwd`:`pwd` -w `pwd` -i -t  ubuntu pwd
```

The `-v` flag mounts the current working directory into the container. The `-w` lets the command being executed inside the current working directory, by changing into the directory to the value returned by `pwd`. So this combination executes the command using the container, but inside the current working directory.

Some helpful links about Dockerfiles:

[Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

[Best Practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)

[Docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

Please let me know if this is helpful.